# How To Join These Threads

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
def run1():
    for i in range(5):
        print("hello")
        sleep(1)
def run2():
    for i in range(5):
        print("hi")
        sleep(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target=run1).start()
    Thread(target=run2).start()
    print("Bye !")
```

i threaded two functions run1 and run2
why is bye printing in between of these threads
i already tried joining them but it doesn't work

Comment: Show the code where you're trying to join them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you are most likely looking for:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    th1 = Thread(target=run1)
    th1.start()
    th2 = Thread(target=run2)
    th2.start()
    th1.join()
    th2.join()
    print("Bye !")
```